# How do pointers in linked lists relate to the lists themselves?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am working on leetcode #61, on rotating the linked list. I understand many of the solutions online, but I don't understand why the solution I came up with doesn't work. The logic seems simple: get two pointers, take one to the last node and the other one to the last-but-one node, then change the `next` nodes to the head and `None` respectively. Do this as many times as needed and return the resulting list. However, some nodes get lost in the way, and I can't figure out why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def rotateRight(self, head: Optional[ListNode], k: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        prev = head
        curr = prev.next
        while k > 0:
            while curr.next:
                prev = curr
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = head
            prev.next = None
            
            k -= 1
            
        return curr
```

Can anybody explain to me where/what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have used nested loops, that will get you an n<sup>2</sup> time complexity. Which will be sufficient to give you a TLE and your answer will not be accepted.
Coming back to your solution, the problem here is that your `head` pointer is not updating(`line number 9 of your code above`) due to which, after each iteration of the outer `while` loop you will lose track of the node pointing your original header node, which will eventually make you loose the remaining nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the `head` and everything works as expected!

Comment: @15b3m if it was helpful.. please accept this answer by clicking on the tick button.